# How to use value in one table's column to determine the column to use in a select in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have a dealer table and a customer table. The customer table joins to the dealer table on dealer number. The customer table has multiple coupons possible to use in a campaign. The dealer table determines which coupon should be used next. My question is using T-SQL, how do I select the customer number from the customer table and the value of the corresponding coupon text in the dealer table? Thanks!

| Customer | Dealer | CouponType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | Coupon2 |
| 101 | 2 | Coupon1 |

| Dealer | Coupon1 | Coupon2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Happy anniversary | Save 10% |
| 2 | Happy anniversary | Save 10% |

Comment: Please see here for how to ask a good SQL question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question
 But high level what have you tried?  Have you looked at JOINS?

Comment: Yes, I have tried declaring a variable and then trying to use the result as text within a query joining the two tables.

Comment: Are you implying your Dealer table is N columns wide with the columns named according to CouponType?

Comment: What database are you using? What programming interface? Unless you normalize data structure, most likely will need a custom function. I use VBA in MS Access. If you use SQLServer or MySQL, might be able to do something in a stored procedure.

Comment: Is CouponType value literally the word "Coupon" with a number suffix as shown? Same for corresponding field names? How many?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out using a cursor.

```
drop table CouponRun
go

create table CouponRun
(IDSEQKEY varchar(50), 
DEALER_NUMBER varchar(50), 
PRODUCT_CATEGORY varchar(100), 
Coupon_Type varchar(100), 
Coupon varchar(1000))
go

DECLARE @IDSEQKEY varchar(50), 
@DEALER_NUMBER varchar(50), 
@CouponType varchar(1000),
@sql varchar(5000)

DECLARE coupon_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select distinct [IDSEQKEY], 
DEALER_NUMBER, 
(case when [PRODUCT_CATEGORY] = 'Industrial' then [COUPON_TYPE3] else 
[COUPON_TYPE4] end) as 'Coupon'
from [Customers]
where DEALER_NUMBER in 
(select distinct DEALER_NUMBER
from [Dealers])
order by [IDSEQKEY]

OPEN coupon_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM coupon_cursor 
INTO @IDSEQKEY, @DEALER_NUMBER, @CouponType

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   
set @sql = 'insert into CouponRun (IDSEQKEY, DEALER_NUMBER, PRODUCT_CATEGORY, 
Coupon_Type, Coupon) select t1.IDSEQKEY, t1.DEALER_NUMBER, 
t1.PRODUCT_CATEGORY, (case when t1.[PRODUCT_CATEGORY] = ''Industrial'' then 
t1.[COUPON_TYPE3] else t1.[COUPON_TYPE4] end), t2.' + @CouponType + ' from 
[Customers] t1, [Dealers] t2
where t1.DEALER_NUMBER = t2.DEALER_NUMBER and t1.IDSEQKEY = ' + @IDSEQKEY + ' 
and t1.DEALER_NUMBER = ' + @DEALER_NUMBER 

exec (@sql)

FETCH NEXT FROM coupon_cursor 
INTO @IDSEQKEY, @DEALER_NUMBER, @CouponType

END
CLOSE coupon_cursor
DEALLOCATE coupon_cursor

go

-------------------------------------------------------

update CouponRun
set Coupon_Type = t2.[COUPON_TYPE2]
from CouponRun t1, [Customers] t2
where t1.IDSEQKEY = t2.IDSEQKEY
and t1.Coupon is NULL
go

-------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @DEALER_NUMBER2 varchar(50), 
@CouponType2 varchar(1000),
@sql2 varchar(5000)

DECLARE coupon_cursor2 CURSOR FOR 
select distinct DEALER_NUMBER, 
Coupon_Type
from CouponRun
where Coupon is NULL
order by DEALER_NUMBER

OPEN coupon_cursor2

FETCH NEXT FROM coupon_cursor2 
INTO @DEALER_NUMBER2, @CouponType2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   
set @sql2 = 'update CouponRun set Coupon = t2.' + @CouponType2 + ' from 
CouponRun t1, [LUP_TCEP_CURRENT_DEALER_OPT_IN] t2
where t1.DEALER_NUMBER = t2.DEALER_NUMBER and t1.DEALER_NUMBER = ' + 
@DEALER_NUMBER2 + ' and t1.Coupon is NULL'

exec (@sql2)

FETCH NEXT FROM coupon_cursor2 
INTO @DEALER_NUMBER2, @CouponType2

END
CLOSE coupon_cursor2
DEALLOCATE coupon_cursor2

go
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a cursor for that.